# How to structure nested views in ui-router in Angular?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm making a categorization tree. I'm using ui-router.

I have some nested views like so:

```
<!-- index.html -->
<div ui-view="">
  category goes here
</div>

<!-- partials/categories.html -->
<div class="category">
  category stuff
  ...
  <div ui-view="subcategory">
    subcategory goes here
  </div>
</div>
```

So when I render path "/categories", categories get populated. Now, I'd like to populate one nested view in the route "/categories/:subcategory". But, all the views in each category get populated with the content that should be shown in only one category (because it's that category's subcategory). How would I do that?

I'd like to see this:

```
Category 1
  subcategory 1-1
  subcategory 1-2
Category 2
Category 3
```

But instead I'm seeing this:

```
Category 1
  subcategory 1-1
  subcategory 1-2
Category 2
  subcategory 1-1
  subcategory 1-2
Category 3
  subcategory 1-1
  subcategory 1-2
```

I'm using ui-router because I need the subcategories to correspond to unique URL paths.

Comment: One option could be to uniquely identify the categories as well in the url: something like `categories/:categoryId/:subcategoryId`.

Comment: Agreed, you should probably track the selected category as a parameter.  Are you `ng-repeat`ing the categories?  You can wrap the `ui-view` in an `ng-if`, to check if that category is the current category